# jQuery focusout event doesn't trigger on table element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a table support multiple row selection (for the moment just the CTRL + mouseclick combination). Everything works fine, but when I click outside the table area, the rows don't deselect. Unfortunately, I have found out that the `focusout` event doesn't trigger at all. Here's my code:

```
$(".library tbody tr").live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected-row');
    } else {
        $(".library tbody tr").removeClass("selected-row");
        $(this).addClass("selected-row");
    }
});

$("table.library").live('click', function () {
    $(".library").addClass("focused");
});

$("table.library").live('focusout', function () {
    $(this).removeClass("focused");
});
```

Has anyone else dealt with this issue?

Comment: The accepted answer applies to your question as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410587/jquery-focus-out-on-tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'focusout' event only fires when focus leaves elements which *can* be focused in the first place, such as input elements. A table element can't get that focus, as far as I know. You'd need to handle the deselection of selected rows in some other way, Lollero mentoned one possible solution in his comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Table element can also get focus if you use tabindex for table body or table element as

```
$('#tableId tbody').attr("tabindex", 1);
```

After this when you click on table it will get focus.