# how to focus a td in a table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to focus a td in a table using jquery?
ie, here the focus will be working on Tabel load

```
function focusco(tableName){
  $(tableName + " td").each(function () {
     var self=this;
     if(data.label==false){
        $(self).trigger('click');
        focus = false;
        return focus;
    }
 }); }
```

This code will note work

Comment: How can you focus a td?

Comment: What do you mean with 'focus'? This is actually something specific to input fields... Or do you mean some kind of highlight?

Comment: @shormz actually i am not sure about that. PLZ help me

Comment: @giorgio actually A Table has many tds. On the tabel load the first td has focused

Comment: @user3487837 ok let me ask it differently... What do you want to achieve? What in your mind means 'focus'? Please illustrate the goal of having a table cell in a so called focused state.

Comment: @giorgio Ok I have a table with 2 rows. firstly my page load execude focusco function. In the function each td will be execude and satisfied the condition we can focus that td
Each td has a text.

Comment: @user3487837 I still don't have a clue of what you want to achieve...

Comment: @giorgio I have trigger click event on load

Comment: @user3487837 and with that last comment you made me even more confused... Come on, look at your question, and think for yourself if the question is that clear that we can understand what on earth you mean...

Comment: @giorgio similiar to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171313/jquery-focusout-event-doesnt-trigger-on-table-element  but here is focus on table but i have focused on td on a table

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna focus a non-focussable element like `<td>`, use `tabindex`:

```
function focusco(tableName){
  $(tableName + " td").each(function () {
     $(this).attr("tabindex", "1");
     var self=this;
     if(data.label==false){
        $(self).trigger('click');
        focus = false;
        return focus;
    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, what they do in the question you posted in the comments, is just marking a row when it's clicked. That's not really what `focus` means in webdevelopment... Anyway, they just toggle a css class to achieve the result, like this (click on a table cell to see what it's doing):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('td').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('focus');
    });
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse;  }
td, th { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; }
td.focus { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>id</th>
           <th>name</th>
           <th>email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Pete</td>
            <td>pete@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>john@live.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Bill</td>
            <td>bill@yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Dave</td>
            <td>dave@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: then change the document ready event to window load event, and alter the javascript accordingly, or try at least to explain what you really want... I give up...

Answer (score 0):

By focus i guess, you want the user to look at it??
For doing that one could change the background color, or add border or change text color or some DOM manipulation to attract attention from user for the particular `<td>`